# How to make a project dependent on another project and Check in to SVN in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, svn, xcode4

I have an SDK project. I am trying to use the result of the SDK project(i.e the libSDK.a) and related files to become dependency for one of my application. Actually I have two apps. One is SDK and the other is a reference application that uses this SDK. Rather than copying this SDK and .h files to Application project whether it can be done directly by XCode?. If so how can I check in both this as a single project to SVN so that somebody can check out both SDK project and Reference app project in a single check out.

Please help if anybody knows it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

An XCode SVN unable to work with externals. Take a look at following tutorial how to bind two projects thru a terminal — http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Short-tutorial-on-svn-propset-for-svnexternals-p.html